# How to define an enumerating type includng an already existing type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm implementing the game of Go in Haskell. I have a type `Point`, that specifies a point on the grid:

```
data Point = Point (Int, Int)
```

I have another type, that represents a game. Among other things it contains `moves`, which is basically a list of `Point`s. Now I need to extend the definition of what a move is to also include the possibility for the player to pass, so I tried this:

```
data Move = Pass | Point (Int, Int)
```

Understandably, the compiler doesn't like this, it complains about `Multiple declarations of ‘Point’`. Only defining `Point` in `Move` also doesn't seem right, though, since I don't exclusively use `Point` in the context of a move. Being able to pass in these places would be weird.

I could use Maybe here, but I wanted to be more specific than that. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What

```
data Point = Point (Int, Int)
```

does is to define the type `Point` with one data-constructor `Point` that takes a tuple of Ints.

I think a better definition of a move would be along the lines of

```
data Move = Pass | Place Point
```

This creates a type `Move` with two constructors, one called `Pass`, and one called `Place` which takes a point. The second one naturally indicates, that the player places a piece at the given coordinate.